# Change asp-page attribute value based on condition in razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, conditional-statements, razor-pages

When a click on a link the pages should be displayed on userroles.Say for example if the userrole is superadmin,then the user will have access to PageA.If the userrole is admin,then the user will have access to PageB. What i tried is ,

```
@if (Context.Session.GetString("userrole") == "superadmin")
                {
                    var HomepageUrl = "/PageA";
                }
                else
                {
                    var HomepageUrl = "/PageB";
                }
                <a asp-area="" asp-page="@HomepageUrl"></a>
```

But im getting error like "HomepageUrl doesnot exist in the current context".
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @King King Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the conditional operator `?:`,here is an [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator),here is a demo:

```
<a asp-area="" asp-page="@(Context.Session.GetString("userrole") == "superadmin"?"/PageA":"/PageB")">link</a>
```

Comment: thanks for giving a solution with official doc and demo. i understood the mistake i have done. I liked your attittude to help others without critisizing their  knowledge in programming. Once again thanks for the help !